# Get a list of media gallery image URL's from getMediaGalleryImages

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, array

I need to get a comma separated list of image URL's from a product's media gallery.

I have successfully managed to load `getMediaGalleryImages` so that if I...

```
var_dump ($product->getMediaGalleryImages());
```

... I can see each image being loaded with it's attributes, i.e:-

```
["url"]=> string(89) "https://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/x/x/x-image.jpg"
```

I just haven't managed to figure out how to list them in an array like:-

```
https://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/x/x/x-image.jpg, https://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/x/x/x-image_1.jpg, https://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/x/x/x-image_2.jpg
```

Struggling to get the syntax right I think...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured this out earlier so here is how I displayed a comma separated list of image URL's from `getMediaGalleryImages`...

```
$gallery_images = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages();

$items = array()

foreach($gallery_images as $g_image) {
    $items[] = $g_image['url'];
}
```

Then I could output with:-

```
implode(', ', $items);
```

Comment: Avoid loading the entire object, it's better to add the gallery images to your collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::app();
$file = fopen('getId.csv', 'r');
$header = fgetcsv($file);
$headers[] = array("id","sku","images");
while ( $row = fgetcsv($file, 6000, ",") ) {
    
    $data = array();
    $data = array_combine($header, $row);
    $id = $data['id'];
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
    $getId = $product->getId();
    $sku = $product->getSku();
    $gallery_images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
    $items = array();
    foreach($gallery_images as $g_image) {
        $items[] = $g_image->getUrl();
    }
    $headers[]=array($getId,$sku,implode(',',$items));
}
$fp = fopen("getImagePath.csv","w");
foreach ($headers as $line) {
    fputcsv($fp, $line);
}
fclose($fp);
```